# Explanation need for unusual piece of code

Tags: c++, syntax

Can you please explain why it's working and why it returns 1 for me.
What type is a? Is it function?

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
};

int main ()
{
    Foo a(int x) ;
    std::cout << a;
}
```

Comment: Did you turn up the warning levels to maximum?

Comment: What does "working" mean here? What are you expecting it to do? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Consider editing the title of this question to make it easier for other people to find.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's a function. In the expression

```
std::cout << a;
```

the function `a` is converted to a function pointer, type `Foo (*)(int)`. The function pointer is then converted to `bool`, because the `operator<<` overload taking `bool` is the only viable one. Since it's not null, the result is `true`, which is printed as 1.

(Note that function pointers can't be implicitly converted to `void*`, unlike object pointers.)